# Reactjs issues during Initial Animation

Tags: animation, reactjs, mount

Still i am getting error -

> Failed prop type: transitionLeaveTimeout wasn't supplied to
>   ReactCSSTransitionGroup: this can cause unreliable animations and
>   won't be supported in a future version of React

My render looks -

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

render(){
        const {...others} = this.props;
        return(<div id="navigation">
            <img id="openNav" onClick={this.handleClick} src={this.state.source}/>
             {this.state.clicked ?
                 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500}>
                    <Navigation {...others} />
                 </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>: false}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

> "react": "^15.2.1",

i dont know where is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you're getting is due to a change documented in the [React v0.14 changelog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html):

> Add-Ons: To improve reliability, CSSTransitionGroup will no longer listen to transition events. Instead, you should specify transition durations manually using props such as transitionEnterTimeout={500}.

The code examples have been updated in [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#getting-started) but the props are not really documented.

You'll need to add these two props (`transitionEnterTimeout` and `transitionLeaveTimeout`) yourself.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
  transitionName="example" 
  transitionAppear={true} 
  transitionAppearTimeout={500} 
  transitionEnterTimeout={500} 
  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
```

You can also disable animating `enter` and `leave` events if you want by using the `transitionEnter={false}` or `transitionLeave={false}` props to `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`.

Comment: Ok, not without any errors, bot without any effect of animation... :( My css looks - 

.example-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}

Comment: Sry, i missed apear in css, now it works (y) thanks a lot

Comment: I was actually writing a comment that since you're forcing animations during the initial mount, you need these CSS too but you found it out by yourself. Excellent.

Comment: And is there any way how to set css of unmount? Opposite of Apear, something like a disappear? :D i tried .example-disappear but it doesnt work

Comment: Not to my knowledge, `appear` is used for the initial appearance and then we use `enter` & `leave`, I think the typical use case is to assume unmount will be the same as `leave`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `transitionLeaveTimeout` to your `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` component, so your render looks with 500ms leave timeout like this:

```
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = require('react-addons-css-transition-group');

 render(){
    const {...others} = this.props;
    return(<div id="navigation">
        <img id="openNav" onClick={this.handleClick} src={this.state.source}/>
         {this.state.clicked ?
             <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                <Navigation {...others} />
             </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>: false}
        </div>
    )
}
```